# How to mark a file dirty from an extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

We have implemented a custom FileSystemProvider in our extension and has a scenario where we need to mark a file provided by our FileSystemProvider as dirty (has unsaved changes) even when user has not modified the file.

Is there a way to explicitly mark a file as dirty from the extension?

Comment: with an edit builder add a space at the end and when that is processed remove the space

Comment: Do you still need to see an example of this?

Comment: Yes, please could you share an example?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to do it.  Basically you do have to make a change to the file and then remove it.

```js
// Method 1

await editor.edit((editBuilder)=> {
    editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(0,0), " ");
}, {undoStopBefore:false, undoStopAfter:false });

await editor.edit((editBuilder)=> {
    editBuilder.delete(new vscode.Range(new vscode.Position(0,0), new vscode.Position(0,1)));
}, {undoStopBefore:false, undoStopAfter:false });

// Method 2

let edits = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();
edits.insert(vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri, new vscode.Position(0,0), " ");
await vscode.workspace.applyEdit(edits);

let edits2 = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();
edits2.delete(vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri, new vscode.Range(new vscode.Position(0,0), new vscode.Position(0,1)));
await vscode.workspace.applyEdit(edits2);
```

I inserted a space at the first character and then removed it.  Obviously, you could insert any character anywhere in the document that you want (like an end of a line) and then remove it.  I don't think there is a better way to do this - you actually have to make a change to the file to get vscode to mark it dirty.  Fortunately for you, undoing that change leaves it as dirty.

This also works (but not for text files which don't have comment characters):

```js
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.commentLine');
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.commentLine');
```

but the toggling is more jarring than adding and removing a space.

I was hoping that simply replacing a character by itself would be the least noticeable but still render the file dirty, but the file is not made dirty - so this does **NOT** work:

```js
let edits = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();

const replaceRange = new vscode.Range(new vscode.Position(0,0), new vscode.Position(0,1));
const textToReplace = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.getText(replaceRange);

edits.replace(vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri, replaceRange, textToReplace);
await vscode.workspace.applyEdit(edits);
```